# Sharing a terminal with multiple users (with screen or otherwise)

Tags: gnu-screen, multiuser

I am setting up a server where there are multiple developers working on multiple applications.

I have figured out how to give certain developers shared access to the necessary application directories using the `setgid bit` and `default ACLs` to give anyone in a group access.

Many of these applications run under a terminal while in development for easy access. When I work alone, I set up a user for an application and run screen as that user. This has the downside that every developer to use the `screen session` needs to know the password and it is harder to keep user and application accounts separate.

One way that could work is using screen multiuser features. They do not work out-of-the-box however, screen complains about needing `suid root`. Does giving that have any downsides? I am pretty careful about using `suid root` anything. Maybe there is a reason why it isn't the default?

Should I do it with `screen` or is there some other intelligent way of doing what I want?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Yes, you can do it with `screen` which has multiuser support.

First, create a new session:

```
screen -d -m -S multisession
```

Attach to it:

```
screen -r multisession
```

Turn on multiuser support:

Press `Ctrl-a` and type (NOTE: `Ctrl+a` is needed just before each single command, i.e. twice here)

```
:multiuser on
:acladd USER ← use username of user you want to give access to your screen
```

Now, `Ctrl-a d` and list the sessions:

```
$ screen -ls
There is a screen on:
    4791.multisession   (Multi, detached)
```

You now have a multiuser screen session. Give the name `multisession` to acl'd user, so he can attach to it:

```
screen -x youruser/multisession
```

And that's it.

The only drawback is that `screen` must run as `suid` root. But as far as I know is the default, normal situation.

Another option is to do `screen -S $screen_id -X multiuser on`, `screen -S $screen_id -X acladd authorized_user`

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is what I tried, up to where screen complains about needing `suid root`. I figured out I'd ask if this was the preferred way of doing things before adding root permissions to programs that do not have them by default

Comment: Strange. My `screen` is `suid` root.

Comment: I think that might be a distro-dependant thing. I tried on CentOS 6 or 7 (need to check)

Comment: For what it's worth, `screen` is also not `suid root` on Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: `screen -S $screen_id -X multiuser on`, `screen -S $screen_id -X acladd authorized_user`  instead of control-a commands would be a good addition to the answer

Answer (score 3):

I've determined that the reason why other people commenting on this question could not do multi-user even after following the steps in @Scyld de Fraud's answer is because SELinux must be enabled (see https://phoenixnap.com/kb/enable-selinux-centos).  Screen requires this for certain functionality, such as assigning the Access Control List (via the screen `acladd` & `aclchg` commands) permissions to limit or grant access to various users on multi-user displays, as well as for restarting zombie sessions.

Answer (score 1):

Original post - [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72138639/15314754) to [How to execute a command inside a screen session](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18406823/4424636):

> It took me some time, but what I found is: Version of **screen 4.06**
> has a bug.  If you want to send a command over a shared screen session
> like this, it fails:
>
> ```
> screen -S shared_session_name -X stuff "command \n"
> ```
>
> Screen fails with an error:
>
> ```
> Cannot opendir /run/screen/S-$USER: Permissions denied
> ```
>
> After updating to the version **screen 4.09** it works.