# Configure screen to have multiuser support

Tags: gnu-screen, multiuser

Following up on [Sharing a terminal with multiple users (with screen or otherwise)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/163872/sharing-a-terminal-with-multiple-users-with-screen-or-otherwise)

Same as the first comment, my screen complains about needing suid root, and

`sudo chmod u+s /usr/bin/screen`

fixes that for me.

However, when the guest tries to connect to the screen session with

`screen -x youruser/multisession`

He's getting:

`chmod /dev/pts/13: Operation not permitted`

How to fix for that?

The bugs at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/screen/+bug/1173312 reported the same issue, yet the conclusion was that it was *"fixed in trusty"* in 2014.

Mine is `Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS`, and I'm still having such `Operation not permitted` issue.

Answer (score 0):

Found it!

First of all, the whole process of configuring screen to have multiuser support can be found at
https://possiblelossofprecision.net/?p=1993

Now, the very last comment,

> If you run into `chmod /dev/pts/2: Operation not permitted` remember that a user is not able to manipulate the pty he is on when you run `su - user` (in contrast to using `ssh user2@host`).

That's exactly my case -- I was trying it myself.

Asking the guest to try with ssh himself works just fine *for him*.